# scrollable panel in swing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

[image: example]

I have a problem when adding a scroll pane to my app. My app works like this:
1. At start panel1(yellow one) is initialized
2. After I press "potvrdit" panel2(red one is initialized)
3. Set of panels(green one) are added to panel2

The problem is that I cant add a scrollbar when the number of set(green panels) is too big for screen. It just added thin line on the right side as you can see.

This is part of my source code:

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Etiket print.");
JPanel panel0 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollFrame = new JScrollPane(panel2);
jframe.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280, 1000));
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();        
panel0.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
panel2.setAutoscrolls(true);
panel3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
panel4.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel container = new JPanel();
JPanel container1 = new JPanel();
JPanel container2 = new JPanel();
container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
container1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
container2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
container1.add(panel0);
container1.add(panel1);
container2.add(container1);
container2.add(panel3);
container2.add(panel4);
container.add(container2);
container.add(panel2);
jframe.add(scrollFrame);
jframe.add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jframe.pack();
jframe.setVisible(true);
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Potvrd")||e.getActionCommand().equals("myTextField")){

                temporaryBlockedSubharnesses.clear();
                panel2.removeAll();

                harnessPanelList.clear();


            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 0.5;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = i;
            JPanel hp= new JPanel();
                hp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 70));
                hp.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 70));
                hp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 70));
                if(i%2==0) {
                hp.setBackground(myBlue1Color);
            }
            else {
                    hp.setBackground(myBlue2Color);
                 }


            panel2.add(hp, c);

               hp.repaint();
              hp.validate();
            }
            panel2.repaint();
            panel2.validate();
            jframe.repaint();

        }
```

Comment: You are adding your scroll panel into the panel its supposed to be scrolling. This probably isn't going to work.

Comment: William is right. You should add the scroll pane to the frame instead.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: JPanel doesn't implements Scrollable, you would need to add

Comment: `setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 800,750));`  See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).

Comment: when i try to change it to jframe.add(scrollFrame), even the grey thin panel on the right side disappear

Comment: Did you also take Andrew's advice and `setPreferredSize` @Michael ?

Comment: I dont get it, what is wrong with setpreferredsize()?

Comment: `setPreferredSize` is executed exactly once, and won't adapt when e.g. the window is resized. Better override `getPreferredSize` instead.

Comment: Don't call setPreferredSize and leave all that to the LayoutManager.

Comment: guys I edited my post and updated my source code according to your advices but i still cant see scrollbar can you help me plz?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `JPanel` try `JXPanel` from swingx library. It implements `Scrollable` so it support scrolling.